# Mock actorRef.tell inside an Actor class

Tags: java, unit-testing, akka, mockito, powermock

I  have an actor class `EmployeeActor`, inside that actor, some other actor is fired using `payrollRunActor.tell()`. I need to write a JUnit test for `EmployeeActor.java`, but I don't want to fire `payrollRunActor.tell()`, means I want to mock it.

Is there a way to do it? I tried a lot, but real `payrollRunActor` is getting fired. 
Here is the actual code of my `EmployeeActor` class.

package com.test.periodic.actors;

```
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.test.avs.domain.boundedcontext.Employee;
import com.test.avs.domain.boundedcontext.PayrollRun;
import com.test.entity.BusinessDTO;
import com.test.periodic.actors.aggregrators.EmployeeAggregator;

import akka.actor.AbstractActor;
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.Props;
import akka.routing.RoundRobinPool;

public class EmployeeActor extends AbstractActor {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmployeeActor.class);
    private boolean rollup;

    public static Props props() {
        return Props.create(EmployeeActorTest.class);
    }

    private List<PayrollRun> payrollRuns;
    private String instanceId;
    private String employeeAggregatorId;
    private Employee employee;
    private ActorRef organizationAggregatorActor;
    private List<BusinessDTO> businessDTOs;

    final ActorSystem payrollRunSystem = ActorSystem.create("payrollRun");

    ActorRef employeeAggregator;

    public EmployeeActor(ActorRef organizationAggregatorActor, List<PayrollRun> payrollRuns,
            Employee employee, List<BusinessDTO> businessDTOs, boolean rollup) {
        this.payrollRuns = payrollRuns;
        this.employee = employee;
        this.organizationAggregatorActor = organizationAggregatorActor;
        this.businessDTOs = businessDTOs;
        this.rollup = rollup;
    }

    @Override
    public void preStart() throws Exception {
        instanceId = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(6);
        employeeAggregatorId = "employeeAggregator-" + instanceId;
        employeeAggregator = getContext().system().actorOf(
                Props.create(EmployeeAggregator.class, organizationAggregatorActor, employee),
                employeeAggregatorId);
        super.preStart();
    }

    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder().match(Employee.class, employee -> {

            if (rollup) {
                logger.info("Rollingup business entities.");
                employeeAggregator.tell(employee, getSelf());
            } else {
                ActorRef payrollRunActor = payrollRunSystem.actorOf(new RoundRobinPool(payrollRuns.size())
                        .props(Props.create(PayrollRunActor.class, employeeAggregator, employee, businessDTOs)));
                for (PayrollRun payrollRun : payrollRuns) {
                    **payrollRunActor.tell(payrollRun, getSelf());**
                }
            }


        }).match(PayrollRun.class, maxPaydatePayrollRun -> {
            ActorRef payrollRunActor = payrollRunSystem
                    .actorOf(Props.create(PayrollRunActor.class, employeeAggregator, employee, businessDTOs));
            **payrollRunActor.tell(maxPaydatePayrollRun, getSelf());**
        }).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably don't want to do this at all.  Use `Probe` in order to replace the `payrollRunActor`.  Mocking this is likely to be a very painful path.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you would have to mock the static method call which is invoked during the creation of class under test. Then make it return a spied object and mock the method you want to avoid calling:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ActorSystem.class)
public void TestClass{

     @Test
     public void test(){
          // Arrange
          PowerMockito.mockStatic(ActorSystem.class);
          ActorSystem actorSystemMock = Mockito.mock(ActorSystem.class);
          Actor actorSpy = Mockito.spy(new Actor());

          Mockito.when(ActorSystem.create("payrollRun")).thenReturn(actorSystemSpy);

          Mockito.when(actorSystemMock.actorOf(any(RoundRobinPool.class)))
            .thenReturn(actorSpy);     

          Mockito.doNothing().when(actorSpy)
            .tell(Mockito.any(PayrollRun.class), Mockito.any(Self.class));

          EmployeeActor employeeActor = new EmployeeActor(); 

          // Act and assert...
          employeeActor.createReceive();
     }
}
```

Remember that all other methods of actorSystemSpy will be called will real implementation. If you want to mock all of them then use `Mockito.mock` instead of spy.

Comment: I have question on below code, tell method is not available on when(actorSystemSpy) because actorSystemSpy is a ActorSystem, not Actor.  Is that correct?
 **Mockito.doNothing().when(actorSystemSpy).tell(Mockito.any(PayrollRun.class), Mockito.any(Self.class));**

Comment: When mocking the tell() method, getting the error **java.lang.ClassCastException: akka.actor.ActorRef$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$ef59ca36 cannot be cast to akka.actor.ScalaActorRef**

Comment: there was a mistake. Make sure you use ActorSystem actorSystemMock = Mockito.mock(ActorSystem.class);

Comment: yes @Maciej, I have written the code that way only, but still getting the error. Here is the code.

Comment: PowerMockito.mockStatic(ActorSystem.class);
        ActorSystem actorSystemMock = PowerMockito.mock(ActorSystem.class);

        Mockito.when(ActorSystem.create("payrollRun")).thenReturn(actorSystemMock);
        ActorRef actorSpy = Mockito.mock(ActorRef.class);
        Mockito.when(actorSystemMock.actorOf(new RoundRobinPool(anyInt()).props(Props.create(PayrollRunActor.class, null, null, null)))).thenReturn(actorSpy);
        Mockito.doNothing().when(actorSpy).tell(Mockito.any(PayrollRun.class), actorSpy);